# Why won't Kotlin print the string I select from a .txt file unless it's the last line?

Tags: kotlin

I'm using to open a text file, randomly select a line, and format a string that includes the randomly selected line. The string is then printed to the console, but for some reason it won't work unless the last line of the file gets randomly selected.

Text file:

```
Neversummer
Abelhaven
Phandoril
Tampa
Sanortih
Trell
Zan'tro
Hermi Hermi
Curlthistle Forest
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File

fun main() {
    var string = File("data/towns.txt")
        .readText()
        .split("\n")
        .shuffled()
        .first()
    println("$string has printed")
}
```

Output when last line is selected:

```
Curlthistle Forest has printed
```

Output when any other line is selected:

```
 has printed
```

Comment: Please minimize the code: [mcve]. Too much irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I guess your OS is Windows. It means that your lines end with `\r\n`, not `\n`. In result, `\r` goes into strings (all except the last one), and messes the things up. Use [readLines](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-lines.html) instead of `readText`+`split`.

Comment: BTW, instead of `shuffle`+`first` you want to use [random](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html).

Comment: I switched to readLines and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by dyukha in the comment section it is indeed a platform specific issue. I prefer the solution (s)he provided using `readLines()` since you can condense two function calls into one.

However, should you ever need to check for the line delimiter in a platform independent manner you should use the built-in `System.lineSeparator()` property (Since Java 7).

```
import java.io.File

fun main() {
    var string = File("data/towns.txt")
        .readText()
        .split(System.lineSeparator())
        .shuffled()
        .first()
    println("$string has printed")
}
...
```

Still, I do recommend that you use `readLines()` since it packages the functionality of both `.readText()` and `.split(System.lineSeparator())`.